# Unable to use println() command in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I am following an online tutorial on how to build apps with Xcode. The video shows how to make a button and connect it to code to print out a statement. I have copied the code from the video 100% but it is not working. I have a more updated version so is there something I need to do differently. I am using Xcode 6.4 and the video was using 6.0.
This is my code:

```
- (IBAction) showFunFact() {
    println("You pressed me!")
}
// Error: Expected method Body
// Error: Semantic issue, Implicit declaration of function 'println' is invalid in C99
// Parse Issue: Expected ';' after expression
```

These are the three errors I am receiving but I think the other 2 are due to the fact that the program dose not recognise the println command. Anyone know how to fix this!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because the function should be declared like so:

```
@IBAction func showFunFact() {
    println("You pressed me!")
}
```

The function you have posted above looks like an Objective-C function, so make sure either that a) your file is not an Objective-C file, or b) if you were trying to use Objective-C, then `println()` won't work because it's not a method defined in Objective-C. In that case, the appropriate method would be `NSLog(@"You pressed me!");`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, I had accidentally selected to use Objective-C instead of swift. It works now!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `println` in Objective-C code. It is a Swift function, so you have to create a Swift file for that.

In Objective-C you could use `NSLog(@"boo!");`

Answer (score 0):

xcode will compile many different type of languages - from swift to C++ to objective C and so on.

I am going through a similar phase and can tell you that many of the tutorials I find online are now irrelevant because antiquated. I would recommend **Stanford's CS 193P lectures** which are refreshed every year and use the latest language / compiler so you can always follow along. (Lectures & docs aval for free in itunesU)